# Setting a hard bracket attribute via typescript

Tags: angular

In one of the libraries I've created, I get the element (usually a button) and set the disabled true value:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
```

And this correctly sets the button as the following:

```
<button type="button" disabled="true">my button</button>
```

However one of the most popular industry leading ui libraries can't work with a string value. It MUST be set like the following (making it a real boolean type value):

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="true">my button</button>
```

But how can I set this via the typescript side since I can't use `nativeElement.setAttribute`? Is it possible? Is this a job for `viewChild`?

Comment: That is a bindning, in your code you're binding true. Give it a variable from the controller and you can change it by changing the value of the variable. Check the documentation  on bindings for more information.

Answer (score 0):

## Property Binding:

In .ts file:-

> allowUser = false

in html:-

> [disabled] = "!allowUser"